# How to give the same dimensions to controls of different types

Tags: css

I have a serie of controls on each row (dropdownlist, textbox, button, ...). I want them to have the same height. The only problem is I need to ajust manualy the height of each element because 25px for Dropdownlist seems not to be the same as 25px for a textbox. The textbox, for instance, are always bigger. Is there a universal way to do that?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can try adding a CSS reset to your page which should help but form elements can be notoriously tricky to make uniform across all browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can apply the following to all the elements you are trying to size:

```
.box-model {
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box; 
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height:32px;
}
```

This will make them, including select boxes adhere to your defined rules. This wont work in older versions of IE. IE6 and 7 are notriously bad at styling select boxes and input fields, and do not support the above CSS.

Comment: As usually, all the browsers are working perfectly but IE9. I just give up.

Comment: Surprising... but not surprising, I generally find IE9 to be ok. What's it doing?

Comment: It's not making the controls higher. Yesterday, No matter when I change the height of those controls, IE9 would stay the same. Maybe, I am missing something.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by controls, you mean the right hand arrow on select boxes? Or the entire `<input>` element?

Answer (score 0):

```
input, textarea, select, select>option { width:150px; height:50px; line-height:50px;}
```